# Zip only files not directory

Tags: powershell

I'm using a script from site [link](http://www.technologytoolbox.com/blog/jjameson/archive/2012/02/28/zip-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx). But it zips the directory. I rather want it to zip only files inside that directory and the zipfile name should be the directory.zip.

Here is the `ZipFolder` function. I'm unsure what needs to be edited in this code to make it zip only files inside a directory.

```cs
function ZipFolder(
    [IO.DirectoryInfo] $directory
) {
    if ($directory -eq $null) {
        throw "Value cannot be null: directory"
    }

    Write-Host ("Creating zip file for folder (" + $directory.FullName + ")...")

    [IO.DirectoryInfo] $parentDir = $directory.Parent

    [string] $zipFileName

    if ($parentDir.FullName.EndsWith("\") -eq $true) {
        # e.g. $parentDir = "C:\"
        $zipFileName = $parentDir.FullName + $directory.Name + ".zip"
    } else {
        $zipFileName = $parentDir.FullName + "\" + $directory.Name + ".zip"
    }

    if (Test-Path $zipFileName) {
        throw "Zip file already exists ($zipFileName)."
    }

    Set-Content $zipFileName ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))

    $shellApp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $zipFile = $shellApp.NameSpace($zipFileName)

    if ($zipFile -eq $null) {
        throw "Failed to get zip file object."
    }

    [int] $expectedCount = (Get-ChildItem $directory -Force -Recurse).Count
    $expectedCount += 1 # account for the top-level folder

    $zipFile.CopyHere($directory.FullName)

    # wait for CopyHere operation to complete
    WaitForZipOperationToFinish $zipFile $expectedCount

    Write-Host -Fore Green ("Successfully created zip file for folder (" +
        $directory.FullName + ").")
}

#Remove-Item "C:\NotBackedUp\Fabrikam.zip"

[IO.DirectoryInfo] $directory = Get-Item "D:\tmp"
ZipFolder $directory
```

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: powershell version 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternate method from [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/456095/zipping-only-files-using-powershell)

```
$srcdir = "H:\Backup"
$zipFilename = "test.zip"
$zipFilepath = "K:\"
$zipFile = "$zipFilepath$zipFilename"

#Prepare zip file
if(-not (test-path($zipFile))) {
    set-content $zipFile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipFile).IsReadOnly = $false  
}

$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipFile)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcdir | where{! $_.PSIsContainer}

foreach($file in $files) { 
    $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
#using this method, sometimes files can be 'skipped'
#this 'while' loop checks each file is added before moving to the next
    while($zipPackage.Items().Item($file.name) -eq $null){
        Start-sleep -seconds 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of PowerShell you are using, seems like v2, and if true, really upgrade to at minimum v5x. v2 is depreciated and no longer supported if memory serves.

Using PSv5, you can just do this...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'e:\temp' -Recurse -Directory | 
ForEach{
    Compress-Archive -Path "$($_.FullName)\*.*" -DestinationPath "$($_.FullName)\$($_.Name).zip" -Verbose
}
```

The walk-thru of the above is...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'e:\temp' -Recurse -Directory


# Results

    Directory: E:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM                Leaf1
d-----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM                Leaf2
d-----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM                Leaf3



Get-ChildItem -Path 'e:\temp' -Recurse -Directory | 
ForEach{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName
}

# Results

    Directory: E:\temp\Leaf1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                        
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                        
-a----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM              0 New Bitmap Image.bmp                                                                                        
-a----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM              0 New Text Document.txt                                                                                       


    Directory: E:\temp\Leaf2


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                        
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                        
-a----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM              0 New Bitmap Image.bmp                                                                                        
-a----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM              0 New Text Document.txt                                                                                       


    Directory: E:\temp\Leaf3


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                        
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                        
-a----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM              0 New Bitmap Image.bmp                                                                                        
-a----       11/15/2018   9:19 PM              0 New Text Document.txt      


Get-ChildItem -Path 'e:\temp' -Recurse -Directory | 
ForEach{
    Compress-Archive -Path "$($_.FullName)\*.*" -DestinationPath "$($_.FullName)\$($_.Name).zip" -WhatIf
}

# Results

What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
E:\temp\Leaf1\New Bitmap Image.bmp
E:\temp\Leaf1\New Text Document.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
E:\temp\Leaf2\New Bitmap Image.bmp
E:\temp\Leaf2\New Text Document.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
E:\temp\Leaf3\New Bitmap Image.bmp
E:\temp\Leaf3\New Text Document.txt".


Get-ChildItem -Path 'e:\temp' -Recurse -Directory | 
ForEach{
    Compress-Archive -Path "$($_.FullName)\*.*" -DestinationPath "$($_.FullName)\$($_.Name).zip" -Verbose
}

# Results

VERBOSE: Preparing to compress...
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
E:\temp\Leaf1\New Bitmap Image.bmp
E:\temp\Leaf1\New Text Document.txt".
VERBOSE: Adding 'E:\temp\Leaf1\New Bitmap Image.bmp'.
VERBOSE: Adding 'E:\temp\Leaf1\New Text Document.txt'.
VERBOSE: Preparing to compress...
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
E:\temp\Leaf2\New Bitmap Image.bmp
E:\temp\Leaf2\New Text Document.txt".
VERBOSE: Adding 'E:\temp\Leaf2\New Bitmap Image.bmp'.
VERBOSE: Adding 'E:\temp\Leaf2\New Text Document.txt'.
VERBOSE: Preparing to compress...
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
E:\temp\Leaf3\New Bitmap Image.bmp
E:\temp\Leaf3\New Text Document.txt".
VERBOSE: Adding 'E:\temp\Leaf3\New Bitmap Image.bmp'.
VERBOSE: Adding 'E:\temp\Leaf3\New Text Document.txt'.
#>

(Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Temp' -Filter '*.zip' -Recurse).FullName

# Results
E:\Temp\Leaf1\Leaf1.zip
E:\Temp\Leaf2\Leaf2.zip
E:\Temp\Leaf3\Leaf3.zip
```